# Как изменить интервал получения почты в Битрикс24?

Tags: битрикс, битрикс24

Подскажите, как в в Битрикс24 (коробка) установить время забора почты по IMAP чаще чем 10 минут?
Выставил всем агентам связанным с почтой 60 сек и все равно почта проверяется раз в 10 минут.
Перенес выполнение агентов в cron - все равно 10 минут.

Comment: А крон у вас битриксовый с какой частотой отрабатывает?

Comment: Каждую минуту
* * * * * /usr/bin/php -f /home/bitrix/www/bitrix/modules/main/tools/cron_events.php

Comment: @nikolaj-sarry, а в cron_events.php какой код должен быть для ПОЛУЧЕНИЯ писем? Я так понимаю, там только отправка.

Comment: Вообще я не знаю откуда вы взяли интервал в 10 минут. У меня на всех коробках письма синхронизируются куда быстрее. Отправку ускорить можно.
10 минут это интервал для POP3 и его можно сменить действительно.

Comment: Если зайти в настройку почтового ящика https://i.imgur.com/9eS0n6h.png
То видно как таймер обновляется каждые 10 минут
При условии что больше никуда не заходить (и другие пользователи тоже)
Если заходить в раздел "Почта", то проверка идет моментально, т.е. забор почты происходит по хитам.
Т.е. прием почты работает примерно так же как в облаке согласно этой инструкции https://i.imgur.com/J1YB4E4.png